# How to setup Windows 10 shared folder to use with Kubuntu in the same LAN

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, samba, shared-folders, kubuntu

I've got my Linux PC with Kubuntu 16.04 and a guest's Windows 10 laptop connected to the same Wi-fi network.

I would like to access (read and write) `C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\One Time Use Folder` in the Windows 10 PC from Ubuntu's desktop, preferably without having to install additional software, maybe via Dolphin + Samba.

So far Kubuntu can see the Windows PC in `Dolphin > Network > SMB > Workgroup > WindowsLaptopName`

But when I try to access it, it asks me for User and Password, the Windows user says he doesn't have a password.

I've created `One Time Use Folder` in his desktop and `right click > Share > Share > Add [Everyone] to the list > Press OK` and tried accessing it by typing `smb://WindowsLaptopName/One Time Use Folder/` and `smb://WindowsLaptopName/Users/User Name/Desktop/One Time Use Folder/` but both ask for User and Password.

¿What are the correct steps to set up a shared folder in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a valid user, or enable the Guest account if you really want to allow anonymous logins. See this related question on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/51645/406435):

> To do what you want you'll have to enable the "Guest" account on the
>   computer hosting the files and then grant the "Everyone" group
>   whatever access you want.
>
> "Guest" is a user account, but its enabled / disabled status is
>   interpreted by the operating system as a boolean "Allow
>   unauthenticated users to connect?" Permissions still control the
>   access to files, but you open things up a LOT by enabling Guest.

Comment: Thanks. Ugh... why to they have to make it so complicated! Apparently I need a MS account to make a new user...